# Would like to know what I am doing wrong and where to go from here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create something with what I have Learned. What I am doing is trying to take todays date, subtract to 91 days prior to todays date. Then compare to a list of individuals and their anniversary dates to see who needs something added. Example. If todays date is 8/12/2021 and I want to go back 91-97 days that would be 05/13/2021-05/06/2021. Then if Jerrys hire date was 05/13/2021 and Berry's hire date was 05/06/2021 and Jacks hire date was 05/17/2021. I want to run a code that would tell me that Jerry and Berry were hired 91-97 days prior. so far I have the code for the

```
require 'date'
now = Date.today
ninety_days_ago = (now - 90)

p ninety_days_ago
```

Then I was tinkering with trying to add the names and using IF statements and nothing would come out right. Like I would make a variable called names and then add jerry and berry and jack with their hire dates but it would not compare their dates to the 91-97 days prior but it would not include Jack because he isn't at 91-97 days yet.

How can I print out the names of the people?

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/ruby/how+to+find+attendance+by+date+range+in+rails%3F

Comment: Hello @Moxx123, welcome to SO. We need a bit more information. Can you show us the code that you have tried when you create Jerry, Berry and Jack, and how you compare their hire date to the 91-97 days date range. And tell us what errors you saw.

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm new to coding ..
> I want to run a code that would tell me that Jerry and Berry were hired 91-97 days prior.

```rb
require 'date'

today = Date.new(2021, 8, 12)

# In most languages this is called an array of objects.
# In ruby, we say "an array of hashes".
hires = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 13) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 6) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 17) }
]

# This is called a function in most languages. 
# In ruby we call all functions like this, "methods"
def report(hires, today)
  hires.each do |hire|
    puts(
      format(
        '%s was hired on %s, which is %d days ago',
        hire[:name],
        hire[:date],
        today - hire[:date]
      )
    )
  end
end

report(hires, today)
```

You can save this to a file like `hires.rb` and run it with `ruby hires.rb`.

Comment: This helped a lot thank you! Just one more thing to add to this! I added Jack's hire date because I did not want him to be included. I only want to show people who have been hired 91-97 days from the current date 90 would be to soon and 98+ should not be listed . So jack was hired 87 days so he shouldn't be on the report. Guess a little more back story. If someone was hired 91-97 days prior to todays date the should receive vacation. So 90 days they are not eligible, and 98 days they should have already been entered for vacation. Ill add what i was thinking or trying in code in next comment

Comment: require 'date'
time = Date.today
anv = time - 91 #this would be also be through time -97
names = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 13) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 6) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 17) }                                                                        So Basically IF anv (#the date minus 91 days) == names ( the anniversary's of the names) 
 puts "#(name) + They need Vacation" ( so this would only show me the people in the list that need it.) Sorry this is a lot but appreciate the help!